# Get socket for urllib2.urlopen return value for HTTP

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to do asynchronous downloading of files using urllib2 but have no succeeded in finding out the socket (or its fileno) to wait for new data for for HTTP requests. Here's what I've already tried.

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from select import select
>>> r = urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
>>> select([r], [], [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 307, in fileno
    return self._sock.fileno()
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'fileno'
>>> r.fileno()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 307, in fileno
    return self._sock.fileno()
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'fileno'
>>> r.fp.fileno()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 307, in fileno
    return self._sock.fileno()
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'fileno'
>>> select([r.fp], [], [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 307, in fileno
    return self._sock.fileno()
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'fileno'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t512553-re-urllib2-urlopen-broken.html.

> The problem is that urlib2 was changed to wrap an HTTPResponse object
>   in a socket._fileobject to get a few more file methods. Except (as
>   reported above) HTTPResponse doesn't have a fileno() method, so when
>   _fileobject tries to use it, it blows up.

The solution

Adding an appropriate method to HTTPResponse:

```
def fileno(self):
    return self.fp.fileno()
```

Or, alternatively, use `urllib.urlopen` instead of `urrlib2.urlopen`.

There is a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1327971) for this issue; it was fixed in Python 3 and in Python 2.7.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue1327971. It in fact appears you're the one who committed the fix for this?